# Why can't my program find the pthread_barrier_init.c file?

Tags: c, linux, pthread-barriers

For school I am working on a project that has 2 reading threads running and 1 writing thread that work around a shared buffer. This shared buffer is some sort of pointer based list that we programmed ourselves. To make it thread-safe I used to pthread_rw_locks and also some pthread_barriers. When i tried to run my code it crashed almost instantly and it gave me a segmentation fault. When using the gdb debugger it gave me the following message:

program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

__pthread_barrier_init (barrier=0x0, attr=0x0, count=2) at pthread_barrier_init.c:47

47  pthread_barrier_init.c: No such file or directory.

When compiling I included the -lpthread flag and I also made sure to include the pthread.h in every file where it was used. Any idea why my program can't find this c file?

EDIT

This is a snippet of the code that I use. (This is barely all code but it goes wrong in this part)

This is my code for the main loop

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    sbuffer_t* buffer;
    sbuffer_init(&buffer);
        return 0;
}
```

This is my code for the buffer

```
/**
 * basic node for the buffer, these nodes are linked together to create the buffer
 */
typedef struct sbuffer_node {
    struct sbuffer_node *next;  /**< a pointer to the next node*/
    sensor_data_t data;         /**< a structure containing the data */
} sbuffer_node_t;

/**
 * a structure to keep track of the buffer
 */
struct sbuffer {
    sbuffer_node_t *head;       /**< a pointer to the first node in the buffer */
    sbuffer_node_t *tail;       /**< a pointer to the last node in the buffer */
    pthread_rwlock_t* lock; 
    pthread_barrier_t* barrierRead; //Barrier to indicate that both reader threads have succesfully read the sensor reading
    pthread_barrier_t* barrierWrite; //Barrier to indicate that a sensor reading has been removed
    pthread_mutex_t* FIFOlock;
    int finished;
};

int sbuffer_init(sbuffer_t **buffer) {
    (*buffer) = malloc(sizeof(sbuffer_t));
    (*buffer)->lock=malloc(sizeof(pthread_rwlock_t));
    if (*buffer == NULL) return SBUFFER_FAILURE;
    pthread_rwlock_init((*buffer)->lock,NULL);
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock((*buffer)->lock); 
    pthread_barrier_init((*buffer)->barrierRead, NULL, READER_THREADS);
    pthread_barrier_init((*buffer)->barrierWrite, NULL, READER_THREADS);
    pthread_mutex_init((*buffer)->FIFOlock, NULL);
    (*buffer)->head = NULL;
    (*buffer)->tail = NULL;
    (*buffer)->finished = CONNMGR_NOT_FINISHED;
    pthread_rwlock_unlock((*buffer)->lock);
    return SBUFFER_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The `No such file or directory` error message is only saying that you don't have the source code of pthreads available, so the debugger cannot show you the source code line at which the segmentation fault happened. This doesn't matter to the execution of your program. It doesn't need the file to run. The cause of the segmentation fault is in the code you wrote and looking at the `pthread_barrier_init.c` contents in the debugger isn't all that helpful. Just `up` a few times in gdb until you reach a frame in your written code, for which gdb should be able to show the source code.

Comment: Re "*The error is in the code you wrote*", yeah, it clearly is. The debugger shows `0` (`NULL` on x86/x86-64) being passed to the `barrier` parameter..

Comment: If you want to ask about the cause of the segmentation fault, you should edit a [mre] causing the fault into the question and ask about that instead. If you really want to see that source file for whatever reason, you need to install the sources, details will depend on your OS/distribution.

Comment: But the segmentation fault happens when I call the pthread_barrier_init() function. After this it crashes and gives the error that the c file of this function can't be found. So it looks like it is necessary for my program to be able to find this c file?

Comment: What do you think `pthread_barrier_t* barrierRead` points to?

Comment: You may be able to install a "detached debugging symbols" package to allow the debugger to step through the pthread_barrier_init() function at C source level. For Debian/Ubuntu type distros, the package with the debugging symbols for libpthread is the "libc6-dbg" package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not an error, just a warning, and it’s not issued by your program, but by the debugger. The debugger tried to help you by displaying the source file where the crash happened. Alas, that source file is not a part of your program, but a part of pthreads library. Since it’s not available, the debugger informs you of this fact, since otherwise you’d expect to see the source line where the problem manifested. gdb has a “show source line” function that gets invoked after a signal/exception is raised, and that function will always print something: either the source line, or an warning message.